# How to check for blank lines after a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a bit new to python but Im working on a project with rflint and want to make a rule that will basically "check" if there are any blank lines after a sentence, and then I could issue some commands based on if it meets that check or not.

I had a few ideas but got stumped pretty quick, but imagine there is probably a nice function for this in python.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and the expected output?

Comment: I don't know what you use but blank line usually means `\n\n` (eventually with some spaces and tabs between both `\n`)

Comment: You can do: `string == string.rstrip()`